# How to add a new line to document by XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have to transform a simple XML file via XSLT. The result should be the original XML input file plus a generated String. The string is generated out of the value from the XML file.

Generating is easy, but how do i insert the complete original XML content in my output xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a complete copy of a XML with XSLT 1.0. Change your output encoding (it is UTF-8 in this sample) and your need for indent (=yes) as you like.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/> 

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- Default: copy everything -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And if you want to add one line of text at the end use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/> 

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- add a line of text at the end of the xml -->
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text>your line of text</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Default: copy everything -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Keep in mind that the last solution (with the text line) does not create a valid XML!

Comment: thanks, i my case i don't care if its valid xml or not. What i don't understand is why the part to create the additional line is called before the copy procedure. Should'nt it be the other way round?

Comment: The templates match to the correspending nodes. It does not matter which you write first. The node `/` is the root node (every xml has a root node). In this root node we apply templates to all children and attributes. The attributes and children match to the template with `@*|node()`. And this template we copy everything and apply again the matching template to all attributes and node (so it calls itself).

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the `copy-of` element either on the base node or the xml file directly.

For example,
`<xsl:copy-of select="document('style.xml')/"/>`